Capture stderr when application error status
There is an error in a Rails application that does not occur in my mac but it does in GitHub Actions test.
I am printing to stderr and I tried to implement Capture stderr in GitHub Actions but it never reaches that step, as all tests stop as soon as one fails.
How do I fix this?
  - name: Run rails tests
    env:
      PGPASSWORD: postgres_password
      RAILS_ENV: test
    run: |
      ...  initialize db, load fixtures...
      bin/rails test 2> test.stderr

  - name: print test results
    run: |
      echo "rails test results:"
      cat test.stderr

Run rails tests fails and print test results does not even run

Never reaches what step? Give a [mre].

By default a step that ends with non-zero exit code will end execution of a job. All follow up steps will be skipped. You can change this default behaviour by modifying the condition that determines when a follow up step is executed:
- name: print test results
  if: success() || failure()  
  run: |
    echo "rails test results:"
    cat test.stderr

Now, print test results step will execute irrespective of the success outcome of the previous steps. It will only be skipped when the job is cancelled.
